# @escaping closure function in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, escaping, structure, completionhandler

Error with this below function `Closure use of non-escaping parameter 'completion' may allow it to escape`

```
func retrieveCannedRecommendedEntities() -> Future<CannedRecommendedEntities, NSError> {
  return Future() { completion in
    self.retrieve(.onboarding) { response in
      switch response {
      case .success(let val):
        let payload: AnyObject = val.value.json! as AnyObject
        let json = JSON(payload)

        guard let suggestions = self.parseEntitiesFromJSON(json, atKey: "suggestion") else {
          completion(SqorResult.error(self.parsingError))
        }

        let teams = suggestions.filter {
          $0.entityType != .Player
        }

        let athletes = suggestions.filter {
          $0.entityType == .Player
        }

        completion(SqorResult.success(Box((teams, athletes))))

      case .error(let error):
        completion(SqorResult.error(error))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using function in swift3 with  xcode 8.2. It throws error by "Closure use of non-escaping parameter 'completion' may allow it to escape". Help me guys if you knew anything about it.

Comment: improved code readability

Answer (score 1):

**A closure is said to escape a function when the closure is passed as an argument to the function, but is called after the function returns.**

If you use for closure asynchrony, mean the closure may be called after the function execution, you need to add `@escaping` .

Even if you have no error compilation, you might have run time error, because the closure memory can be released.

**`@escaping` assure you to prevent your closure.**

Comment: Thanks for the response.Can you help me how could I add @escaping to the  completion.

Comment: add @escaping before the completion handler

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error means that the parameter `completion` in function `Future`-  which is a closure - is specified as "non-escaping" (this is the default). This means, that the closure `completion` must be executed *before* function `Future` returns.

However, the implementation indicates that `completion` may "escape" the function `Future` - which means, that `completion` may be executed *after* function `Future` returns.

In order to fix this programmer error, you need to ensure that the closure `completion` will be executed *before* function `Future` returns, or you need to add the modifier `@escaping` to the parameter `completion`.

See also [Escaping Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Note, that both solutions may have implications, because they either need a change of the API of a function possibly defined in an existing library (e.g. "Future") or it is incompatible with your use-case, since you call `completion` in another - possibly escaping - closure which is set as a parameter in `self.retrieve`.

However, the notion "completion" in the context of a "Future" clearly dictates, that `completion` should be "escaping". So, adding `@escaping` to the function signature of `Future` seems to be to way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Can you help me how could I add @escaping to the  completion.

Comment: @saranya Please read here [Escaping Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html). (scroll down a bit)